# Request to undelete question "Which browsers support HTML5 offline storage?"

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I favorited *[Which browsers support HTML5 offline storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194784)* a while ago because of the quality and usefulness of the answers. It may no longer be a complete answer as it refers to Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, etc., but it is still a VERY useful answer and one that I haven't found anywhere else on the Internet.

It was unfortunately deleted by a moderator, so I can't do an undelete vote.

Comment: As jjnguy stated, http://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage is a *much* better place to find this information.

Comment: @animuson -- except that it's not.  It provides the necessary support table, but not usage info especially on older versions of IE.

Answer (score 9):

Negative.  It's too localized, and unlikely to be actively maintained so that the information is up to date.

I've added the link to [Can I use Local Storage](http://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage) to the tag wiki for [local-storage](/questions/tagged/local-storage).

Answer (score 4):

I don't really think the question merits being undeleted, for a couple of reasons:

1. As others have pointed out, not only here but also on the original question, it's hopelessly out of date because the answers were written well before the HTML 5 specification was finalized.
2. There's only one answer there that's even any good. The rest are pointless one-liners—noise.

Since you really wanted that one good answer, I'll repost it here for you:

> Wikipedia has a table [comparing the various browser engines and what
>   portions of HTML5 they support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML_5)#APIs).
>
> A [reposted internal Yahoo! article](http://wonko.com/post/search-pad-browser-storage) also details some differences
>   between localstorage support, to quote:
>
> > **Firefox 3.5, Safari 4, IE8, Chrome 4+**: [HTML5 localStorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/); these modern browsers all support the core localStorage functionality
> >     defined in the HTML5 draft.
> >
> > **Firefox 2.x and 3.0**: [Gecko globalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage), a very early implementation similar to HTML5’s localStorage.
> >
> > **Safari 3.1 & 3.2**: [HTML5 Database Storage](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), because Safari 3.1 and 3.2 don’t support HTML5 localStorage.
> >
> > **IE6, IE7**: [userData persistence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424%28VS.85%29.aspx), a rarely used IE feature for associating string data with an element on a web page and persisting
> >     it between pageviews.
> >
> > **Google Chrome Pre 4**: [Gears Database API](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/upcoming/api_database.html), which is built into earlier versions of Chrome and thus doesn’t require a separate
> >     install.

If you want a place where you can post and maintain *updated* answers to a similar question, then I recommend forgetting about this one and asking a new question. And when you do so, make sure that you do it in such a way that it fits within our Q&A format and lends itself to *specific*, constructive answers.

Comment: Even if he wanted that one good answer, he can see it anyway.

Comment: @bolt: Yeah, I didn't look to see that he had 10k before I posted that answer. Oh well.